# Passing params in jsf page using just curly braces - how does it work?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am working on some code in our web project written by somebody else. I am trying to understand the following. First comes this:

```
<rich:contextMenu id="conMenu">
  <rich:menuItem icon="i.png">
    <h:outputText value="#{rootgen.viewAction}" />
    <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{someBean.id}" value="{id}" />
  </rich:menuItem>
</rich:contextMenu>
```

Then this:

```
<rich:componentControl event="onRowClick" for="contextMenu" operation="show">
  <f:param value="#{row.id}" name="id" />
</rich:componentControl>
```

I don't get who is responsible for resolving 'id' value in the first code snippet. Who is the one able to understand only curly braces? rich:componentControl is being used for javascript actions, right? So, when user clicks on a row, parametar named 'id' gets a value. But then, who converts {id} to that value before assigning it to bean property?